# Lambda Expressions and Stored Procedures

Tags: c#, database, lambda

I'm trying to mimic the LINQ Where extension method for my ADO.NET DAL methods.

Bascially, my aim is to have a single method that I can call.  Such as:

```
Product p = Dal.GetProduct(x => x.ProductId == 32);
Product p2 = Dal.GetProduct(x => x.ProductName.Contains("Soap"));
```

I then want to dissect those Predicates and send the filter options to parameters in an ADO.NET Stored Procedure call.

Any comments greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a substantial task to undertake.  Have you considered using Linq2Sql or Linq2NHibernate (i.e. use an off-the-shelf DAL/ORM)?

Answer (score 9):

As @Daniel points out, this is far from simple. The solution outline is to let  `GetProduct` take an argument of type `Expression<Func<Product, bool>>`. You then have to traverse the parse-tree of this expression, generating the correct SQL for functions known and also decide how to handle unknown functions. There are basically two options for that:

1. Throw an error (as linq-to-sql does).
2. Skip it in the translation and then apply it on the returned result. The performance impact of this can of course be huge if a lot of data is retreived just to be filtered out.

It would be a fun exercise to do it - but I can hardly see a way to justify it in the real world, when there are already linq2sql, linq2entities and linq2NHibernate that does the job.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Anders's answer, I just want to mention that you can analyze the expression tree by using an expression visitor. To do that, you can inherit the [`ExpressionVisitor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx) class (it's new in .NET 4, but you can find a 3.5 implementation in [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx)) and override the methods you want to analyze each node.

You might also be interested in those links :

- [Building a LINQ Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/ee672195.aspx)
- [Walkthrough: Creating an IQueryable LINQ Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546158.aspx)